# How to make a symbol by joining together 'P' and 'A'?

Tags: fonts, symbols

'P' should be in the left of 'A' and of little smaller size.

Comment: Could you show a picture ?

Comment: Please, tell whether it is for math mode and the vertical position of P.

Answer (score 3):

Here I link them together with a small rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\stackengine{0pt}{{\footnotesize P}\kern-2.5ptA}{\kern1pt\rule{3pt}{.3pt}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

like this ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}

{P\scriptsize\hspace{-1em} A}

{\scriptsize P}\hspace{-1em} A

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whether 'P' could be made small compared to 'A'?

Comment: Yes! I got it from your suggestions. Rather I used : 
\newcommand{\PA}{^P\hspace{-6pt}A}

Answer (score 2):

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\textsc{p\kern-.3emA}$

\end{document}
```